# Why does my SSRS page height expand when running subreports in a local processing mode ASP.NET report viewer?

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a report with subreports and when running subreports it's as if the subreport height is not being taken into account.

So for example ...
if I had a report where 10 lines that would fit on each page and then mofified that report by adding a subreport that had child data (say 2 or 3 lines for each of the 10 lines of parent data), the 1st page of my modified report still tries to fit all 10 lines of the main parent data and as a result, the first page is actually very, very tall looking.

I'm...

- Using a dynamically generated rdlc file.
- Handling SubreportProcessingEventHandler to get the data for each subreport
- Using the v9 version (the one that comes with VS 2008)

NOTE: The same RDL works fine when used in the equivalent WinForms report viewer.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of the HTML generated page.  It may help in finding what is causing this.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what I'm supposed to be looking for in the html.

Comment: Actually just found out that the same behaviour does happen on the WinForms version of the report viewer too but only in Normal display mode (I was viewing the Winforms version of the report in PrintLayout display mode where it works as I expected). 
I think I'm coming to the conclusion that this is just a "feature" and that in Normal mode the report viewer is not trying so hard to fit the data onto an actual page size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a "feature" (see my comments)